# Adding a new message with required fields to protobuf v2

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

Say, I have two versions of proto file:

> version 1.0 - initial version
>   version 2.0 - adds a new message with required fields

Is this a valid change in proto file from compatibility point of view ?

IMHO since `v2.0` defines a new message with required fields, it should cause backward in-compatibility since if a message is sent from `v2.0` to `v1.0`, `v1.0` will not understand it, it wouldn't know how to decode it. And since it is marked `required`, `v1.0` can't even ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding new required fields to an *existing* message type is a backwards-incompatible change, because old servers won't ever send that field.

Adding a whole new message type with required fields is backwards-compatible, because old servers won't be sending that message at all. For example, say we start with:

```
message Old {
  required int32 i = 1;
}
```

Then we add a new message:

```
message Old {
  required int32 i = 1;
  optional New m = 2;
}

message New {
  required string s = 1;
}
```

This is backwards-compatible. When an old program sends a message to a new program, the field `m` will be absent, which is fine because it is optional. The required field `m.s` is only required if `m` itself is present.

When a new program sends a message to an old program, the field `m` will be ignored. `required` does NOT mean that the receiver can't ignore it. `required` only means that the sender is required to send it.

Note that I strongly recommend against using `required`. Proto3 removed `required`, and Cap'n Proto never had it in the first place, because of the unexpected problems it can cause. [Here's an in-depth discussion I wrote.](https://capnproto.org/faq.html#how-do-i-make-a-field-required-like-in-protocol-buffers)

(Disclosure: I'm the author of Proto2 and Cap'n Proto.)

Answer (score 0):

Protocol Buffers does not handle the recognition of the type of message. That part is something that is done in the application code.

So the answer to this question depends on what the application does when it receives unknown message. It may either ignore it or raise an error - you will have to check the code to know.